# Pages and posts on ElegantTheme featured slider

Tags: themes

I use an [ElegantTheme](http://www.elegantthemes.com) on a wordpress site.

These themes have a "featured" slider on the home page. In the administration panel of the theme, you can choose wether you want to show featured articles (blog posts) or pages. You can select which posts or pages you want on the slider.

But, there is no option to mix both pages and articles.

I believe one may achieve this by editing the `featured.php` file from the theme :

```
<?php

    $responsive = 'on' != get_option('aggregate_responsive_layout') ? false : true;
    $featured_auto_class = '';
    if ( 'on' == get_option('aggregate_slider_auto') ) $featured_auto_class .= ' et_slider_auto et_slider_speed_' . get_option('aggregate_slider_autospeed');
?>

<div id="featured" class="<?php if ( $responsive ) echo esc_attr( 'flexslider' . $featured_auto_class ); else echo 'et_cycle'; ?>">
    <a id="left-arrow" href="#"><?php esc_html_e('Previous','Aggregate'); ?></a>
    <a id="right-arrow" href="#"><?php esc_html_e('Next','Aggregate'); ?></a>

<?php if ( $responsive ) { ?>
    <ul class="slides">
<?php } else { ?>
    <div id="slides">
<?php } ?>

<?php
    $arr = array();
    $i=0;

    $featured_cat = get_option('aggregate_feat_cat');
    $featured_num = (int) get_option('aggregate_featured_num');

    if (get_option('aggregate_use_pages') == 'false') query_posts("posts_per_page=$featured_num&cat=".get_catId($featured_cat));

    else {
        global $pages_number;
        if (get_option('aggregate_feat_pages') <> '') $featured_num = count(get_option('aggregate_feat_pages'));

        else $featured_num = $pages_number;
        $featured_page_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'page',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'posts_per_page' => (int) $featured_num,
            );

        if ( is_array( et_get_option( 'aggregate_feat_pages', '', 'page' ) ) )
                $featured_page_args['post__in'] = (array) array_map( 'intval', et_get_option( 'aggregate_feat_pages', '', 'page' ) );
                query_posts( $featured_page_args );
} ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
global $post; ?>

<?php if ( $responsive ) { ?>
            <li class="slide">
<?php } else { ?>
            <div class="slide">
<?php } ?>

<?php

                $width = $responsive ? 960 : 958;
                $height = 340;
                $small_width = 95;
                $small_height = 54;
                $titletext = get_the_title();

                $thumbnail = get_thumbnail($width,$height,'',$titletext,$titletext,false,'Featured');
                $arr[$i]['thumbnail'] = get_thumbnail($small_width,$small_height,'',$titletext,$titletext,false,'Small');
                            $arr[$i]['titletext'] = $titletext;
                $arr[$i]['post_id'] = get_the_ID();
                $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"];

                print_thumbnail($thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height, ''); ?>
                <div class="featured-top-shadow"></div>
                <div class="featured-bottom-shadow"></div>
                <div class="featured-description">
                    <div class="feat_desc">
                        <p class="meta-info"><?php esc_html_e('Posted','Aggregate'); ?> <?php esc_html_e('by','Aggregate'); ?> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> <?php esc_html_e('on','Aggregate'); ?> <?php the_time(esc_attr(get_option('aggregate_date_format'))) ?></p>
                        <h2 class="featured-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        <p><?php truncate_post(410); ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="readmore"><?php esc_html_e('Read More', 'Aggregate'); ?></a>
                </div> <!-- end .description -->
        <?php if ( $responsive ) { ?>
            </li> <!-- end .slide -->
        <?php } else { ?>
            </div> <!-- end .slide -->
        <?php } ?>
        <?php $i++; endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php if ( $responsive ) { ?>
    </ul> <!-- end .slides -->
<?php } else { ?>
    </div> <!-- end #slides -->
<?php } ?>
</div> <!-- end #featured -->

<div id="controllers" class="clearfix">
    <ul>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $featured_num; $i++) { ?>
            <li>
                <div class="controller">
                    <a href="#"<?php if ( $i == 0 ) echo ' class="active"'; ?>>
                        <?php print_thumbnail( array(
                        'thumbnail'     => $arr[$i]["thumbnail"]["thumb"],
                        'use_timthumb'  => $arr[$i]["thumbnail"]["use_timthumb"],
                        'alttext'       => $arr[$i]["titletext"],
                        'width'         => (int) $small_width,
                        'height'        => (int) $small_height,
                        'et_post_id'    => $arr[$i]['post_id'],
                        ) ); ?>
                        <span class="overlay"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <div id="active_item"></div>
</div> <!-- end #controllers -->
```

Sorry for such a big piece of code, but I'd rather provide the whole file just in case.

I tried to remove the `if (get_option('aggregate_use_pages') == 'false')` test and always do both the `query_posts` and what's in the `else`, but all this does is always show the featured pages, even if you choose to show the articles in the admin panel.

Is there any way to ignore the choice you make in the admin panel and show both featured articles and pages ? Thanks.

Comment: This is a commercial Theme. You paid for support when you bought the Theme. Have you tried ElegantThemes support?

Comment: I read the support forums. Their answer to the same question is "You are trying to customize the theme, and this is beyond the purpose of this forum, you should hire a developer to do it". They say (and I can understand that), that they concentrate their efforts in helping people use the themes the way they are supposed to be used. They can't help everyone tweak their themes unfortunately :)

Comment: They also say the answer is to change how posts and pages are queried from the database in the featured.php file, so I guess I'm on the right track.

Comment: Full answer from the support : "Hello! I am afraid that this ticket goes beyond the level of support that we can provide here. We cannot guarantee support with theme customizations, and while we would love to help you, we must focus on ensuring that our themes are working as intended and as previewed in our theme demos. If you would like a custom solution that goes beyond what our themes provide, then we would suggest hiring a third party developer to assist you." (I don't want to make them look bad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably many problems here, starting with the use of `query_posts()` for a secondary query.

The proper method is `new WP_Query()`, passing the relevant arguments. For example

```
$featured_query_args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page' ),
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => (int) $featured_num,
    'post__in' => (array) array_map( 'intval', et_get_option( 'aggregate_feat_pages', '', 'page' ) )
);

$featured = new WP_Query( $featured_query_args );

if ( $featured->have_posts() ) : while ( $featured->have_posts() ) : $featured->the_post();

    // Loop markup here

endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Note: this is *untested* example code, to help you construct a proper secondary query and loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm trying to work with that. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Your answer works nicely, thanks a lot. Sorry for the off-topic question, I thought this was the best place to ask it.

Comment: It's mainly only off-topic because, without the rest of the commercial code, any deeper issues specific to the code can't be diagnosed/explained. That's why this answer is fairly generic. I'm glad it helped you! :)